# PHP - I need to log all the variables (POST, $_SESSION, Arrays) into a file

Tags: php

I need to log all the variables and string into a log file for monitoring my project. 
The new log file should generate every day with current date.
eg: if todays date is 02-10-2015, then the log file name should be 02_10-2015.txt

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Sure anyone can help you, but did you try anything by yourself or you want us to write code for you?

Comment: Do you have any actual code that you tried to show us ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ob_start() PHP build in function for turn out put buffering on. So in between ob_start() and ob_end_clean(), the values will not be shown in the web browser.

For detailed description you can refer this link [php-write-log-file-php](http://blog.lindosebastian.com/php-write-log-file-php)

You can use below code for generating the log file.

```html
ob_start();
print_r($array);
echo "Any String";
$getContents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$logFileName = fopen('log_'.date("j.n.Y").'.txt', 'a+') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($logFileName, $getContents );
fclose($logFileName);
```